# Suitable datatype to store hours

Tags: sql-server

I want to store hours in the database. The scenario is something like this that I have to store the minimum total hours for an employee until he's marked Early out. For example if the total hours spent in office of an employee are less than 7:30 than she/he left early.
What should be the proper data type for this ?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at data type [`time`, available from SQL Server 2008.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql) However, note that that's actually a data type referring to the part of a type such as `datetime` - so it explains time of day and therefore goes up to 24 hours.

If you need to calculate longevity (for example how long was someone at work) I'd always suggest having two timestamps (for example `datetime2`) and then working out the difference with `DATEDIFF()`. This way you have more flexibility in the future as well because you can dynamically choose whether you want to find a difference in seconds, minutes, hours, etc.

Comment: The second paragraph is the correct response.  Keep in mind that handling dates and times can get complicated, especially when taking things like daylight savings into account, not to mention crossing day boundaries.  Using anything other than DATETIME and DATEDIF() will come back to bite you in the arse.

Answer (score 1):

Given your scenario, you likely don't need to store more than 24 hours. In that case, the best match is the time datatype.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql